# Вызов из Java программы функции написанной на C++

Tags: eclipse, java, c++

Вызов из Java программы функции написанной на C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JNI Example](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html)

> Этот пример показывает, как можно использовать интерфейс Java Native (JNI) для вызова собственных методов, что реализует вызовы C-функций для отображения файлов в память.

Comment: а есть еще статьи?

Comment: есть еще гугл и кучей статей по запросу, типа JNI